# How to fix upgrade hang from saucy->trusty: "Removing ___ from Mono"

Tags: 14.04, 13.10, upgrade, mono, do-release-upgrade

On a recent upgrade from Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy) to 14.04.1 LTS (trusty), the process kept hanging at multiple `prerm` and `postrm` scripts for removing [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) packages.  The symptom of the problem are messages like the following in the `dpkg` output (`/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-term.log` if using `ubuntu-release-upgrader`):

```
$ egrep -B1 'Removing.+ from Mono' /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-term.log

Preparing to unpack .../libdbus1.0-cil_0.7.0-5ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Removing libdbus1.0-cil from Mono
--
Preparing to unpack .../libdbus-glib1.0-cil_0.5.0-4ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Removing libdbus-glib1.0-cil from Mono
--
Preparing to unpack .../libgdata2.1-cil_2.2.0.0-2_all.deb ...
Removing libgdata2.1-cil from Mono
--
Preparing to unpack .../libmono-addins0.2-cil_1.0+git20130406.adcd75b-3_all.deb ...
Removing libmono-addins0.2-cil from Mono
--
Preparing to unpack .../libnotify0.4-cil_0.4.0~r3032-7_all.deb ...
Removing libnotify0.4-cil from Mono
--
Preparing to unpack .../libtaglib2.1-cil_2.1.0.0-3_all.deb ...
Removing libtaglib2.1-cil from Mono
--
Preparing to unpack .../libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil_1.0+git20130406.adcd75b-3_all.deb ...
Removing libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil from Mono
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer has a typo where it said to run
`sudo sed -i -e 's/trusty/saucy/g; s/14.04.1/13.10/g; s/LTS//;'`
but didn't say what file to apply that edit to.

My guess is that they meant /etc/lsb-release and editing that file (as well as /etc/apt/sources.list as shown) worked for me.

P.S. The website said I didn't have enough karma or whatever to post a "comment", so posting this "Answer" (really a comment) was the only choice...

Also, here's a script which automates the repetive ps/run-by-hand/kill procedure described in the previous answer (run the script as many times as necessary to get past the hangs)

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e -u
unset GREP_OPTIONS GREP_COLOR GREP_COLORS
line=$(ps xa -o pid,cmd | grep 'postrm\|prerm' | grep -v grep)
[ -n "$line" ] || { echo "No postrm/prerm cmd is running now." >&2; exit 1; }
pid=$( echo "$line" | sed -ne 's/^ *\([0-9][0-9]*\) .*/\1/p' )
cmd=$( echo "$line" | sed -ne 's/^ *[0-9][0-9]* *//p' )
eval "sudo $cmd"
echo -n "Kill pid $pid ? "
read reply
case "$reply" in
 [yY]*) (set -x; sudo kill $pid)
        && sleep 1 \
        && sudo kill $pid >/dev/null \
        && (set -x; sudo kill -9 $pid)
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks for the script & noticing the typo!  I did indeed mean the `/etc/lsb-release` file.  I'll go ahead and fix that.

I just posted an answer to my own question to help add what I learned & how to work through the problem for future googlers, but I'm kinda glad that this site didn't let me accept the answer for a while... Always helps to have a reminder to go back and fix things & review other answers that crop up to see if they're better ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The process was hanging on the `prerm` and `postrm` scripts for the following packages:

```
Preparing to unpack .../libdbus1.0-cil_0.7.0-5ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Removing libdbus1.0-cil from Mono
--
Preparing to unpack .../libdbus-glib1.0-cil_0.5.0-4ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Removing libdbus-glib1.0-cil from Mono
--
Preparing to unpack .../libgdata2.1-cil_2.2.0.0-2_all.deb ...
Removing libgdata2.1-cil from Mono
--
Preparing to unpack .../libmono-addins0.2-cil_1.0+git20130406.adcd75b-3_all.deb ...
Removing libmono-addins0.2-cil from Mono
--
Preparing to unpack .../libnotify0.4-cil_0.4.0~r3032-7_all.deb ...
Removing libnotify0.4-cil from Mono
--
Preparing to unpack .../libtaglib2.1-cil_2.1.0.0-3_all.deb ...
Removing libtaglib2.1-cil from Mono
--
Preparing to unpack .../libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil_1.0+git20130406.adcd75b-3_all.deb ...
Removing libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil from Mono
--
Preparing to unpack .../libappindicator0.1-cil_12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Removing libappindicator0.1-cil from Mono
--
Preparing to unpack .../libgmime2.6-cil_2.6.20-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Removing libgmime2.6-cil from Mono
--
Setting up mono-gac (3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
* Installing 3 assemblies from libappindicator0.1-cil into Mono
```

To force removal of the packages, I identified the `prerm` and `postrm` scripts that were hanging, ran them manually, and then killed the hung process.  I had to do this multiple times during the release upgrade:

### To Fix

1. Find the hung `prerm` or `postrm` script and run it manually:
   `eval "sudo $(ps xa -o cmd | grep 'postrm\|prerm' | grep -v grep)"`
   You should see output similar to: `Removing libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil from Mono` for whichever package is hanging.
2. Kill the hung `prerm` or `postrm` script:
    `ps -ef | grep 'prerm\|postrm' | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs sudo kill -9`
3. Repeat on next hung package with message: `Removing ___ from Mono`

### If You Encounter Errors:

During my upgrade, I encountered a `postinst` script failure for one of the mono packages (`mono-gac`... more like `mono-gack!!`).  I followed my initial procedure above, except with that `postinst` script.  However, this caused me a problem which killed my upgrade and left the upgrade utility in a broken state.

The errors from my upgrade log were (edited for brevity... see [full log here](https://gist.github.com/502e038851641de14ce2)):

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mono-gac
 mono-runtime-common
 mono-runtime-sgen
 mono-runtime
 libmono-corlib4.5-cil
[...SNIP...]
 libmono-csharp4.0c-cil
 gbrainy
 libdbus1.0-cil
 libdbus-glib1.0-cil
 libgdata2.1-cil
 libmono-addins0.2-cil
 libdbus2.0-cil
 libdbus-glib2.0-cil
 libnotify0.4-cil
 libtaglib2.1-cil
 banshee
 banshee-extension-soundmenu
 libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil
 libmono-simd4.0-cil
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
Log ended: 2014-09-29  14:27:33
```

Then your upgrade process must have failed.  You'll need to force quit the upgrade program, reset things back to your prior release, and then re-start the upgrade:

1. If you're using the GTK release upgrader: Press Ctrl-C and say `Yes` to the prompt asking if you really want to quit.
   If it still doesn't quit... force quit it with:
   `ps -ef | grep do-release-upgrade | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9`
2. Reset your release back (for example, I reset back to `saucy` release from `trusty`):
   `sudo sed -i -e 's/trusty/saucy/' /etc/apt/sources.list`
   `sudo sed -i -e 's/trusty/saucy/g; s/14\.04\.1/13.10/g; s/LTS//; /etc/lsb-release`
   For example, your file should look like:

`DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.10
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=saucy
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.10"`

3. Re-run the upgrade with: `sudo do-release-upgrade`